# Is it possible to have a QMaemo5ListPickSelector which displays images as items?

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to know if its possible to have a QMaemo5ListPickSelector but one which displays rectangular images as list items instead of text ? Is this possible ? If not, is there any other list-like object in Qt which can show images as items instead of text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access list view using QMaemo5ListPickSelector::view() and set item delegate for this view using QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegate(). In delegate item's visual presentation is pretty much unlimited. See Star Delegate example to get into the details of delegate's implementation
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt-maemo/itemviews-stardelegate.html